# Prove spectral radius of a primitive matrix is 1

Tags: spectral-radius

Let $P \in M (n \times n, \mathbb{R})$ be a primitive matrix. $1$ is a eigenvalue of $P$ and $(1,\dots,1)$ is the associated right eigenvector.

How can show that the spectral radius $\rho(P):=$max$\{|\lambda| : \lambda$ is a eigenvalue of $P\}$ of $P$ is 1?

Hint: Use Gelfand's formula.

Comment: a primitive matrix is stochastic, and alla stochastic matrices have 1 as spectral radius

Comment: @Exodd Unfortunely no.

Comment: Why not? $P$ is stochastic, and in the link is proved that the spectral radius of a stochastic matrix is 1

Comment: How can I use Gelfand's formula to prove it? It is not included in the link.